# Unsuppress Android Studio warnings

Tags: android-studio, lint

In order to get it off my back, I suppressed a few warnings in Android Studio -- only warnings regarding formatting issues like font size and button styles.

In retrospect, I'd rather I hadn't, since I'm now at a point where I'd like to ensure my code complies with all the relevant styling guidelines.

So, how do I unsuppress these warnings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio, open Preferences and select Editor -> Inspections from the side menu. You should see a large, collapsible list where you can change what potential problems will be indicated and their severity. The screenshot below shows an example of this window in Android Studio 2.0.

If you remember fairly well what settings you want to revert, you can search for them and re-check the box. You can also select the gear icon above the list to reset it to default settings.

If you have warnings that you are relatively sure you can ignore but don't want hidden completely, just change the severity to a lower level. Changing a 'warning' to a 'weak warning' or 'info' will cause the indicator to be a little less annoying and if you are using the built-in version control tools, allow you to pass the pre-commit code analysis.

JetBrains has a pretty good support article [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-inspection-severities.html), which covers all this and how to further customize inspections.

[image: Inspections preferences]

Comment: Thats annoying...it will be good to have just one button to reset inspections to default.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, everything you suppress is in the format of `@Suppress....`. Therefore, what you can do is right click on your project folder (from inside of AndroidStudio), click "Find in Path..." and search for "@Suppress".

Comment: This finds two occurrences in my project of `@Suppress`, neither of which relates to the warnings I've suppressed.  I've suppressed these warnings in one of my xml layout files.

Comment: @drmrbrewer What is the format of those suppressions in your xml layout files? Also, make sure you are trying to find in path from the parent folder that also contains the folders with the xmls

Comment: Yep, I've searched from the top level folder and directly within the layout folder.  Nothing.  All I did to suppress the warning was choose from the lightbulb dropdown that appears when you click on the element being warned about, and chose 'suppress'.

Comment: @drmrbrewer do the suppressions in your xml layout have a different format or they search doesn't find them for some reason?

Comment: Can't see any extra suppression stuff in the xml... it looks like it's all the xml layout stuff that I put in.